# How to get Index value of a particular element

Tags: jquery

How to get Index value of a particular element. i was using `index()` but i'm not getting the index value. may b the syntax is wrong

```
 <div>click me</div>
 <div class="test">test</div>
```

JS

```
 (function(){

        var test = $('div.test');

        $('div').each(function(i){

            if($(this).index(test) > 0)
            {
                alert('the index of test class div is : ' + $('div.test').index(this) + '.');
            }

        });

    })();
```

Comment: What do you want to check `test` against? The class name? The text value? etc.

Comment: Have you read [the examples in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/index/)? Your `index` will always return 0 with the given html.

Comment: the div with the class of test is at index 1 . i just want the index value 1

Comment: @Daniel: in most modern programming environments the first element has index 0, not 1.

Comment: var test = $('div.test');  var index = $( "div" ).index( test ));

Answer (score 0):

(as @axel.michel  mentioned in comments The each Method already includes a counter parameter, you'll don't need to use the index method in that case)

you can use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').each(function(index){ 
        if($(this).hasClass('test')){
            alert(index);
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/8e02xd30/3/)

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('div').each(function(){ 
            if($(this).hasClass('test')){
                alert($(this).index());
            }
        });
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/8e02xd30/1/)

Comment: The each Method already includes a counter parameter, you'll don't need to use the index method in that case. See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8e02xd30/2/

Comment: @axel.michel  you are totally right .. I updated my answer